# Page break functionality is not available in froala with Angular 17 implementation

Tags: froala

I am trying to integrate the Froala editor with my angular17 application. So I was not able to find the solution for page break. So is there any another feature available in this editor or what.

Please suggest how can I develop the page break functionality with my angular17 application with froala editor.

Thanks in advance.
Vaibhav Chaudhary

i have tried in angular17 but not able to find the solution for page break.

if page break functionality is different in froala please let me know.